# logstash configuration grok parse timestamp

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to parse

```
[7/1/05 13:41:00:516 PDT]
```

This is the configuration grok I have written for the same :

```
\[%{DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS:S Z}\]
```

With the date filter :

```
input {
file {
path => "logstash-5.0.0/bin/sta.log"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}
filter {
grok {
match =>" \[%{DATA:timestamp}\] "
}
date {
match => ["timestamp","DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS:S ZZZ"]
}
}
output {
stdout{codec => "json"}
}
```

above is the configuration I have used.

And consider this as my sta.log file content:

```
[7/1/05 13:41:00:516 PDT]
```

Getting this error :

```
[2017-01-31T12:37:47,444][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] fetched an invalid config {:config=>"input {\nfile {\npath => \"logstash-5.0.0/bin/sta.log\"\nstart_position => \"beginning\"\n}\n}\nfilter {\ngrok {\nmatch =>\"\\[%{DATA:timestamp}\\]\"\n}\ndate {\nmatch => [\"timestamp\"=>\"DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS:S ZZZ\"]\n}\n}\noutput {\nstdout{codec => \"json\"}\n}\n\n", :reason=>"Expected one of #, {, ,, ] at line 12, column 22 (byte 184) after filter {\ngrok {\nmatch =>\"\\[%{DATA:timestamp}\\]\"\n}\ndate {\nmatch => [\"timestamp\""}
```

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to  specify the input for your `grok`filter. A correct configuration would look like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "logstash-5.0.0/bin/sta.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {"message" => "\[%{DATA:timestamp} PDT\]"}
  }
  date {
    match => ["timestamp","dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss:SSS"]
  }
}

output {
  stdout{codec => "json"}
}
```

For further reference check out the `grok` documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html).

Comment: but still doesnt seem to work with this config yet.. is there anything wrong at the configuration level

Comment: @SoundaryaThiagarajan I forgot a curly bracket. I edited my answer.

Comment: getting _dateparsefailure

Comment: Your date string is wrong aswell. I edited my answer again.

Comment: Sure.. Can you help me with the screenshot which I attached now - I am trying for this log -- Sample log: Fri Jul 01 13:44:28 2005

Comment: You should really read up on the [`grok`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and [`date`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) reference. You are mixing up the two.